# Hey, how can we integrate Dialogflow CX with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to use some in-built agents from CX but since I have used Dialogflow ES json file, I think I am unable to integrate CX and ES using the same json file.

Comment: Are you trying to export the Dialogflow ES agent and import it into Dialogflow CX? As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#export), Dialogflow ES and Dialogflow CX agent types are incompatible. You cannot restore an incompatible agent.

Comment: No, I actually cannot find CX json key to import it in my project. But since the file was downloaded via console.google.com under the keys section, I always thought that CX and ES, both would get called....
Is the way I'm thinking:- wrong?

Comment: We can use the same service account and the respective json key file for both Dailogflow CX and ES with the required permissions. For more information on using the service accounts refer to this quickstart of Dailogflow [CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/setup#auth) and [ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/setup#auth). Also, can you provide the error message you are getting while using the ES json key file with Dailogflow CX? Make your question clear by adding necessary details as per Stack Overflow [Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).